# innodb_file_per_table option enabled but ibdata1 file still grows up

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I installed mariadb 10.2.10 with `innodb_file_per_table` option enabled.

Then I create table with `Innodb` engine and inserted 1 M row into.

Now I look and local (`..data/mydbname/table_name.ibd`)   file is grown, but  grown system `ibdata1` file also. Why? I expected that because of `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled, only local `.ibd` should grown, but not `ibdata1`.

Why size of `ibdata1` also grows up? What I misunderstood ?

Comment: what size you have set in your configurations for innodb_data_file? the default ibdata1 has MySQL instance native data used for undo/redo operations and for innodb_file_per_table would split data table wise. Any table created with this option would let you have two files .frm and .ibd..hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of operations use `ibdata1` temporarily.  The actual data for the given table will be entirely in the `.ibd` file.

It's rather normal for ibdata1 to be at least tens of MB, even with all tables in their .ibd files.

Do you have the following case?

1. `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`
2. Create and populate `table1` -- this will go into `ibdata1`
3. change to `innodb_file_per_table=ON`
4. Create and populate `table2` -- this will go into `table2.ibd`
5. insert into `table1` -- this will *still* go into `ibdata1`

The way to *move* an existing table to `ibd` is to set ON, then do

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If this does not explain your situation, please keep an eye on (1) what operations are being performed on *any* table, and (2) the size of ibdata1.  If it grows again, the (1) may give us some more clues.

Note especially any operations involving large tables.